# Found nil when unwrapping non nil value

Tags: ios, swift, null, unwrap

I'm trying to make a get request in swift passing the following parameters

```
var dict = [
    "id_struttura" : 2,
    "prenCheck" : [
        "codice" : "14:30_15:20_1_3831_0",
        "id_sport" : 6,
        "ora_fine" : "20/02/2015 15:20:00",
        "ora_inizio" : "20/02/2015 14:30:00",
        "rec" : 0,
        "soci" : [
            [
                "esterno" : 0,
                "id" : "1980"
            ],
            [
                "esterno" : 0,
                "id" : "51"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

using the following method:

```
private func genericRequest(method: Methods, url: String, data: [String: AnyObject]?) -> AnyObject?{
    var getRequest : NSURLRequest?
    var postRequest : NSMutableURLRequest?

    if method == Methods.GET{
        var completeUrl = url

        if(data != nil){
            //println(data)
            completeUrl += "?"
            for (key, value) in data! {

                completeUrl += "\(key)=\(value)&"
            }
            completeUrl = completeUrl.substringToIndex(completeUrl.endIndex.predecessor())
        }
        //println(completeUrl)

        let url = NSURL(string: completeUrl)
        getRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    }else if method == Methods.POST{
        postRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        postRequest!.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var params : String = ""

        for (key, value) in data! {

            params += "\(key)=\(value)&"
        }
        params = params.substringToIndex(params.endIndex.predecessor())

        var err: NSError?
        postRequest!.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    }

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var request = getRequest != nil ? getRequest! : postRequest!
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

    //println((response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
    let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var json: AnyObject? = convertDataToJSON(reply)
    return json
}
```

calling it as `genericRequest(Method.GET ,url:url, data: dict)` (as Method is simply an enum) it can't unwrap the data variable in `for (key,value)in data!` when making a get request, but it can when it's making a post request. Since I have to use only get requests for this task (i'm dealing with a bad rest interface), could someone help me?

UPDATE:
I also tried with `if let data = data { ...` and it crashes on this line saying  `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Have you checked if that action is available on server? Have you tried to Curl it or send request via http/ Advanced Rest client?

Comment: You need to set the .method on NSURLRequest to your selected method I think post is default but if you're going to use get then getRequest.method = "GET"

Comment: yes, it does. The server takes almost all the requests in get

Comment: maybe i didn't explain well, this code just crashes in the first `for (key, value) in data!` because it finds data = nil when it isn't. I think this has nothing related to the connection

Comment: Have you checked that data is nil or are you just assuming that?

Comment: I checked it, data is not nil. Also, i'm passing it as a parameter so I'm sure that's not nil

Comment: Print out key and value and inside the for loop and see what it tries to use.

Comment: Because your dict has 2 keys in it where key 1 is Int and key 2 is NSDictionary, when the for loop is coming to key 2 it tries to treat NSDictionary as a String and I think thats where it chrashes

Comment: It simply doesn't enter the for loop!
And no, dict has 2 keys, each of them is a String and 2 values, a int and a NSDictionary. the method it expecting dict to be [String: AnyObject], so i can't see the problem (remember, the same code, a couple of lines below, works)

Comment: The error is on `getRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)` line. `url` is `nil`. Because `completeUrl` contains `\n` characters.

Comment: No @rintaro, the execution stops before that line

Comment: I meant value for key is Int but whatever. If completeUrl is not nil then you have a very weird problem probably an xcode bug on your hands.

Comment: If what you are talking about is the line Xcode pointed on. It's not true.

Comment: For me it's true. I'm testing this code on a playground, and it crashes on the line I was saying, as if data is nil while it isn't (and I know it isn't nil as I pass it as a parameter)

Comment: I mean, it's a Xcode bug :). The actual error line is not there. This problem seems to be fixed in Xcode 6.3 Beta, try it.

Comment: Oh.... you're in playground... I tested in a project and it worked for me...

Comment: Yes, is it so different?

Comment: Ive had some werid bugs before when using playground, its stil very new and is bound to have a few bugs still.

Comment: The strange thing is that the same code works some lines below

Comment: Could be like @rintaro says aswell, since Swift came out xcode has had problems showing exactly where it crashes, add a breakpoint in first line in your function and go step by step and see where it crashes

Comment: But I can't debug in playground and I have to make this function work BEFORE putting it into xcode project

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of force unwrapping (`!`). Each place where you do that is a place where you are promising the compiler that the optional will never ever be nil. In most places I think that you should allow the compiler to prove the nil safety by using other methods of dealing with optionals (optional chaining, nil coalescing, map etc.)

In your specific case I don't know why you aren't doing:

```
if let data = data {
```

instead of:

```
if (data != nil) {
```

and then having to force unwrap data with `!`.

I recently [blogged](http://blog.human-friendly.com/how-i-handle-optionals-in-swift) and [talked](http://blog.human-friendly.com/beyond-if-let) about the tools for dealing with optionals in Swift if you want more information about how not force unwrap.

Comment: I tried it, but even if i use `if let data_ = data { ...` the application crashes saying 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' (even if I know that the variable is not nil)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not checking if data is nil in your POST method as you did in GET method. I think the post method is where you are trying to unwrap nil

```
if method == Methods.GET{
    var completeUrl = url

    // here you check if data is nil
    if(data != nil){
        //println(data)
        completeUrl += "?"
        for (key, value) in data! {

            completeUrl += "\(key)=\(value)&"
        }
        completeUrl = completeUrl.substringToIndex(completeUrl.endIndex.predecessor())
    }
    //println(completeUrl)

    let url = NSURL(string: completeUrl)
    getRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

}else if method == Methods.POST{
    postRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    postRequest!.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params : String = ""
    //check here as well
    if data != nil{
        for (key, value) in data! {

            params += "\(key)=\(value)&"
        }
        params = params.substringToIndex(params.endIndex.predecessor())
    }

    var err: NSError?
    postRequest!.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
}
```

Comment: No, the error is in the GET method as this is a private method and i made two function wrappers: `func getRequest(url: String, data: [String: AnyObject]?) -> AnyObject?{
        return genericRequest(Methods.GET, url: url, data: data)
    }` and `func postRequest(url: String, data: [String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject?{
        return genericRequest(Methods.POST, url: url, data: data)
    }` so there's no need to check in the post method